# preg_replace nested html tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to transform regular nested html tags :

```
<section class="foo">
<h1>My title <span style="color:#F00;">is awesome</span></h1>
<a href="#blog"><img src="assets/img/blog.jpg" class="blog"/></a>
</section>
```

into custom nested tags :

```
{{section.foo}}
{{h1}}My title {{span style=color:#F00}}is awesome{{end-span}}{{end-h1}}
{{a href=#blog}}{{img.blog src=assets/img/blog.jpg}}{{end-img}}{{end-a}}
{{end-section}}
```

You can see that the class attribute needs to be next to the tag name, just separated with a dot.

I'm not very familiar with regexp expressions, so it's a pain in the ass to find something...

Any ideas ?

thks :)

Comment: You would surely need a html parser for this. Dom ?

Comment: You're going to have fun when trying to convert it backwards when handling nested elements of the same type if using regex.